# How do i delete a message in discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have made a bot, and when I updated to discord.js v12 I change the code to v12 but I get this error
here is my code
I have tried to uninstall and then install the discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.delete();
    let totalSeconds = (bot.uptime / 1000);
    totalSeconds %= 86400;
    let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    totalSeconds %= 3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);

    let uptimeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${bot.user.username} Bot Uptime`)
    .setColor("#e56b00")
    .addField("Hours", hours)
    .addField("Minutes", minutes)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`Lavet`)
    
    message.channel.send(uptimeEmbed).then(message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })).catch(console.error)
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "uptime" //NAVNET ER LIG MED KOMMANDOEN
}
```

This is the error I get when I try

```
C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:126:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/791725159362330635/messages/798219060780466196',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you try to delete the same message twice.

First, in `message.delete();`, and next in
`message.channel.send(uptimeEmbed).then(message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })).catch(console.error)`

For context, error code 10008 in the Discord API means that the message could not be found, which makes sense in the current situation.

In order to fix this, assuming that the second message.delete is trying to delete the uptimeEmbed message sent by the bot, you can do this:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let channel = message.channel;
    message.delete();

    let totalSeconds = (bot.uptime / 1000);
    totalSeconds %= 86400;
    let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    totalSeconds %= 3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);

    let uptimeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${bot.user.username} Bot Uptime`)
    .setColor("#e56b00")
    .addField("Hours", hours)
    .addField("Minutes", minutes)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(`Lavet`)
    
    channel.send(uptimeEmbed).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })).catch(console.error);
}
```

Instead of attempting to delete the same message twice, this stores the channel in a variable, send the message to the channel, and then deletes its own message.